# Eliminar elementos

Tags: javascript, typescript

tengo la siguiente problemática.
Necesito eliminar del array opciones los valores que estén el atributo id del objeto. 
Por Ej:

array

```
opciones = [1, 2, 3 ,4 , 5]
```

objeto:

```
[
//0:
{id: 1, texto: "CAMAS"},
//1:
{id: 2, texto: "MUEBLES"}
]
```

Este me debería retornar el siguiente array:

```
newOpciones: [3, 4 ,5]
```

Comment: **objeto** no tiene una estructura valida, el 0: y el 1: deben estar enmascaro como tales con `{ }`. ¿Estos forman parte del objeto o solo esta para ilustrar?

Comment: Tanto como el **Array** y el **objecto** no tienen sintaxis correcta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso la solución tanto en typescript como en javascript es similar, solo en typescript cambia `var` por `let`

```js
var opciones = [1, 2, 3 ,4 , 5]
var objetos = [
 {id: 1, texto: "CAMAS"},
 {id: 2, texto: "MUEBLES"}
]
   
//Obtienes solo los ids ya seleccionados. 
var ids = objetos.map(x=>x.id)
//Filtramos las opciones. 
var newOpciones= opciones.filter(opcion=> {
    //Si el arreglo de ids incluye opcion, entonces lo convertimos en false
    // con !
    return !ids.includes(opcion)
} )
//La linea anterior puede quedar como opciones.filter(o=> ids.includes(o))
// para que este mas resumida.
console.log(newOpciones)
```

## Referencias

[filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

[includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu tienes son dos arrays, uno de números y otro de objetos.

**Sólución (Javascript)**

```
"use strict";
let options = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const objects = [
    { id: 1, texto: "CAMAS" },
    { id: 2, texto: "MUEBLES" },
];
for (const index in objects) {
    const id = objects[index].id;
    console.log('ID: ' + id);
    options = options.filter((value, key) => {
        console.log('Value: ' + value);
        if (id !== value)
            return value;
    });
}
console.log(options);
```

**Sólución (TypeScript)**

```
interface objectsImp {
    id: number;
    texto: string;
};
let options: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const objects: objectsImp[] = [
    { id: 1, texto: "CAMAS" },
    { id: 2, texto: "MUEBLES" },
];

for (const index in objects) {
    const id: number = objects[index].id;
    console.log('ID: ' + id);

    options = options.filter((value: any, key: number) => {
        console.log('Value: ' + value);
        if (id !== value)
            return value;
    });
}
console.log(options);
```

He dejado las trazas, la **salida por consola** será:

```
ID: 1
Value: 1
Value: 2
Value: 3
Value: 4
Value: 5
ID: 2
Value: 2
Value: 3
Value: 4
Value: 5
(3) [3, 4, 5]
```

**Explicación:**

Recorro los objetos para obtener cada ID.
Una vez que tengo la ID del objeto, voy a recorrer las opciones usando `Array.filter()` que devuelve un array *mutado* con los elementos que cumplen la condición: *el número de opción no es igual a la ID*.